# Reports are blank when opened from Reports Server

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have created a report project in Visual Studio 2013 and deployed a test report to the local reports server (SSRS 2012).

When I preview the report from visual studio it opens well, but when I try opening it from Report Server URL, I can see the report viewer toolbar but once I click "View Report" it shows "Loading" and then a blank page appears.

I then tried to delete the datasource, datasets and delete any report contents and just keep the title, still a blank page is the only thing that appears

Any idea what could be the problem or things i can try ?

Comment: Use a profiler trace to see if ReportServer is sending the expected SQL call to the correct database.   Have you uploaded all shared datasources to the report server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a problem in Chrome browser, trying out Internet Explorer worked fine.